# Link moz-extension as a href

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mozilla

Is possible to link moz-extension in html code like `<a href="moz-extension://..."`?

I want to link this in my html page:

```
<a href="moz-extension://c93d166a-2b26-49f1-865c-adc733d30743/site/index.html" target="_blank">test</a>
```

But link doesn't open...

Any solution?

Comment: you've tagged `google-chrome` ... why? clearly chrome won't know what a `moz-extension://` is ... are you running this in chrome?

Comment: Because chrome has extension too. I thought maybe that can be similar.

Comment: are you trying this in chrome or firefox

Comment: Yes, I tried in firefox and link doesn't open